# How do I get class annotations from a Method instance?

Tags: java, reflection

Consider the following `class`:

```
@ClassAnnotation1
@ClassAnnotation2
class MyClass {

    // ...        

    @MethodAnnotation1
    @MethodAnnotation2
    private void myMethod(@ParamAnnotation1 @ParamAnnotation2 int i) {
    // ...
    }
}
```

During a reflection phase of my application, I need to analyze various code aspects, given a `Method` instance.

```
public void analyze(final Method method) {
    // do the analysis...
    // for example here, method is an instance of myMethod in MyClass
}
```

I can easily analyze the **parameters**' `Annotation` by doing

```
for (Parameter p : method.getParameters()) {
    if (p.getAnnotation(ParamAnnotation1.class) != null) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and get the results I expect.

The **method**'s `Annotation`'s can easily be processed with

```
method.getAnnotation(MethodAnnotation1.class)
```

---

Unfortunately I fail to get the expected results for the **class**' `Annotation`'s.

In fact, the call to

```
method.getClass().getAnnotation(ClassAnnotation1.class)`
```

returns `null`, whereas `MyClass` is clearly annotated by `@ClassAnnotation1`.

How do I get the `MyClass` annotations from a `Method` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `method.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(ClassAnnotation1.class)`

---

The fact that `method.getParameters()` returns the method's **parameters**, probably mislead you into thinking that `method.getClass()` returns the **class** containing your method.

`Method::getClass()` in fact returns `Class<? extends Method>`, which is clearly not annotated by `@ClassAnnotation1`. That's why you got `null`